# Why am I getting "Unexpected value ''" error in this GitHub action?

Tags: github-actions

I have a GitHub action step like this (extracted from a larger `test.yml` file):

```yaml
    steps:
    - name: Parse
      shell: bash
      env:
        TYPE: ${{matrix.package-type}}
        BV: ${{matrix.builder-version}}
        # This comment is line 63, the "#" is in column 9
        NULL: ${{ matrix.beta-version }}
      run: |
        echo TYPE is "$TYPE"
        echo BV is "$BV"
        printf "Null is '%s'\n" "$NULL"
```

When I run it, I get the following error:

```
The workflow is not valid. .github/workflows/test.yml (Line: 64, Col: 9): Unexpected value ''
```

Why is this line invalid? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 14):

If you're using a reusable workflow, make sure you're not passing `runs-on` to the job that `uses` the workflow. The `runs-on` is contained in the workflow file itself, not in the top level job.

> The workflow is not valid. .github/workflows/REDACTED.yml (Line: 123, Col: 5): Unexpected value 'uses' .github/workflows/REDACTED.yml (Line: 124, Col: 5): Unexpected value 'with'

Answer (score 4):

It turns out there is some quirk in the GitHub action YAML parser that treats `NULL` as a special token. I guess it parses

```yaml
NULL: ${{ matrix.beta-version }}
```

as if it were

```yaml
'': ${{ matrix.beta-version }}
```

Changing `NULL` to `null` does not help. (Side note, keys to `env` must be unique when compared in a case-insensitive comparison, meaning you cannot have both `FOO` and `foo`, even though the case is preserved when setting the environment variable name.)

The best fix/workaround is to avoid using "NULL" and use something else, like "NIL". However, if you must use "NULL", you can do it by putting it in quotes:

```yaml
"NULL": ${{ matrix.beta-version }}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was because `go-version` looked like this in the matrix section:

```
  matrix:
    go-version: 1.17
    os: [ubuntu-latest, macos-latest]
```

It needed to be changed to an array: `[1.17]`